# Importing module issue

Tags: python, module, python-import

I'm making a simple image editing Tkinter program but when I try to import the `PE_functions.py` file I made to make the `main.py` code cleaner I get an error (they're in the same folder) saying:

*AttributeError: module 'PE_functions' has no attribute 'add_top_menu'*

## main.py

```
from tkinter import *
import PE_functions

root = Tk()

PE_functions.add_top_menu()

main_frame = Frame(root, width=500, height=400)
main_frame.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

## PE_functions.py

```
from tkinter import *
import main


def add_top_menu():

    # adds menu bar
    top_menu = Menu(main.root)
    main.root.config(menu=top_menu)

    # creates sub menu called "file"
    file_menu = Menu(top_menu, tearoff=False)
    top_menu.add_cascade(label="File", menu=file_menu)

    file_menu.add_command(label="New")
    file_menu.add_command(label="Open")
    file_menu.add_separator()

    file_menu.add_command(label="Save")
    file_menu.add_command(label="Save as")
    file_menu.add_separator()

    file_menu.add_command(label="Exit")

    # adds "edit" sub menu
    edit_menu = Menu(top_menu, tearoff=False)
    top_menu.add_cascade(label="Edit", menu=edit_menu)

    edit_menu.add_command(label="Flip")
    edit_menu.add_command(label="Rotate")
    edit_menu.add_command(label="Crop")
```

Comment: Look's like you have a circular import: (`PE_functions.py` imports `main.py` and `main.py` imports `PE_functions.py`).

Comment: @ChristianDean so I should probably add a “master/root” argument to replace main.root then removing the main import in PE_functions.py?